# A smarter clang-tidy run: only check changed files & other source files that include a changed header?

Tags: c++, git, gcc, clang-tidy

We use the run-clang-tidy script to check the whole component after a build like so:

```sh
run-clang-tidy-12 -p build -header-filter="(src|libraries)" src libraries
```

We would like to run this (by changing the parameters) only on the files that are changed and for all source files that include a changed header file. As we're using git, maybe together with gcc it can give use that list of files.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost everything imaginable here is already at pre-commit.com

Comment: @torek if you say A, you must say B :)  I’m aware of pre-commit, but tell me more which module can do such a thing!

Comment: If I had the answer I would have answered instead of commenting...  I just know that pre-commit.com has a lot of stuff!

Comment: It's funny that I know C++ is supported by pre-commit, but it's not in the supported language list :p  What I'm not sure it's capable of is finding out the source files that included a changed header file... I'll start digging.